# getting geographical locations using google Api

Tags: c#

i want to show locations of a particular City (e.g. London or any other city). i want to show locations using windows forms or windows presentation foundation. but i didnt knw how to get locations using Google API.  Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for: http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/